# Facebook graph api returns 400 bad request with correct access token

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, curl, oauth-2.0, bad-request

I just manually implemented a facebook oauth2 flow into my webapp. After receiving the correct access_token and trying to call the graph api for user data I got a 400 BAD REQUEST as response.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?accessToken=MY_CORRECT_TOKEN&fields=id,name,email
```

When I use exactly the same call within the dev tools provided on facebook it succeeds, but when I try using any other http client it doesnt work. 
I already tried it with curl, apache commons and some other http clients.

Is there someone able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this? Same problem here. All answers found online are useless and don't address the issue.

Comment: Hi, it was really just like said in the answer. I forgot the underscore in "accessToken" -> "access_token"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of your API call is incorrect. Try the following instead:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=MY_CORRECT_TOKEN&fields=id,name,email
```

The `accessToken` in your URL should actually be `access_token`.

Answer (score 1):

For people landing here with the same error message but different problem, you can also check, if you have both IPv4 and IPv6 connections, that both IPs (v4 and v6) are authorized in Facebook OAuth parameters (on developer.facebook.com). That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my "permanent" access token expired.